# Where is quartz-1.6.5 on maven repositories?

Tags: java, maven, repository, quartz-scheduler

I can find versions from `1.0` to `1.5.2` under `quartz:quartz`, also I can find version `1.6.1` under `org.opensymphony.quartz:quartz` and versions from `1.7.2` to `2.1.6` under `org.quartz-scheduler:quartz`.

Where is `1.6.5`? Are there any search engines with version query?

Why do they rename group all the time???

Comment: Searchin in Maven Central simply like this: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|quartz

Answer (score 2):

I found that quartz-1.6.5 is in JBoss third-party repository: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/org/opensymphony/quartz/quartz/1.6.5/

Answer (score 1):

quartz is very old(2009), you can use [quartz-scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)